# Onion Architecture in .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-core-rc2

I want to create an onion type architecture with the .net core (RC2) framework.

I have created a Console Application (.NET Core) and 5 Class libraries (.NET Core)

- Example (console)
- Example.Logic
- Example.Logic.Interfaces
- Example.Repository
- Example.Repository.Interfaces
- Example.Model

Example.Logic has references to Example.Logic.Interfaces, Example.Repository.Interfaces and Example.Model

Example.Repository has references to Example.Repository.Interfaces

For dependency injection I rely on Autofac (Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection). In Example.Logic and Example.Repository I have autofact modules that registers the interfaces and concrete classes.

```
public class Configuration : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<EmployerLogic>().As<IEmployerLogic>();
    }
}
```

my console looks like this

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterModule<Logic.Configuration>();

        var container = builder.Build();
        GetEmployers(container);
    }

    private static void GetEmployers(IContainer container)
    {
        var employerLogic = container.Resolve<IEmployerLogic>();

        employerLogic.GetEmployers();

        var repository = container.Resolve<Repository.Interfaces.IRepository<string>>();
    }
}
```

Because I have referenced Example.Logic I now also have access to Example.Repository.IRepository. See the **var repository = container.Resolve...**

So my questions are:

- Why does Example has access to the IRepository interfaces? It is not referenced by the console app.
- How can I prevent IRepository from being accessible in the console layer?

Comment: I think this is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/37963523/41071.

Comment: I think you are right :)

Comment: Just replied to the duplicate. The questions is very much the same. Can you close the question?