# .NET Core 1.1 allowing access to indirect dependencies types

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, .net-core-1.1

I created a new .NET Core 1.1 solution and noticed an odd behavior: if I create multiple projects in the solution and chain-reference them, I'm able to freely access types located in a dependency of a dependency, any level down.

This is an example:

[image]

We have a *Sandbox* solution, a *Baz* class library project, a *Bar* class library project referencing *Baz* and a *Foo* console app project referencing *Bar*.

From the *Foo* project I'm able to access and use *BazThing*, a type defined in the *Baz* project, even though *Foo* doesn't have a reference on *Baz*.

This works with NuGet packages too: if I add Entity Framework to *Baz* through NuGet I'm able to use the *DbContext* type in the *Foo* project.

This is a huge problem when the projects are used to implement layer segregation.

Developers are now allowed to access and use implementation details of the dependencies or bypass layer segregation, both "maliciously" and by mistake (in the above mentioned example, IntelliSense will happily suggests to use *BazThings* when typing *ba* without any warning).

Is this how things will work from now on, or are we missing something?

Is it possible to prevent/inhibit this behavior somehow?

Where can I find documentation about this behavior?

Comment: This is a new feature in new VS 2017

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transitive references in .Net Core 1.1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42431299/213550)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37963523/showing-classes-from-indirectly-referenced-packages-in-net-core/38038192#38038192

Comment: Packages are not security boundaries...

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy the question is not regarding security.

Answer (score 2):

That is intended behavior of modern NuGet/msbuild. It is called [meta-packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/packages)/[transitive dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/dependency-resolution) and used for example for the `NETStandard.Library` package to include all libraries of the base class library. I do not think there is a way hiding them. Expect this feature to be added to full .NET Framework projects within the next releases of VS.

Aside of your questions, my personal opinion here is that hiding artifacts behind reference trees is maybe useful at first sight but does not bring any architectural benefit. A loaded assembly can be invoked. One way or the other. Layering, layer bridging and adherence to architecture can be only teached/learned/reviewed/documented. Teach the devs but do not build walls around them. Discipline should not be enforced by the artifacts but by the devs themselves.

Comment: Re _"hiding artifacts behind reference trees is maybe useful at first sight but does not bring any architectural benefit"_: the problem is this affects NuGet packages too: if the NuGet package _Foo_ is used in our project, and _Foo_ inside uses NuGet package _Bar_, in our project _Bar_ is suddenly available; if _Bar_ gets used by mistake - or unknowingly - and an update to _Foo_ drops _Bar_ our projects suddenly explodes because we've relied on an implementation detail of _Foo_. Is encapsulation no longer a core concept of programming?

Comment: Re _"Layering, layer bridging and adherence to architecture can be only teached/learned/reviewed/documented. Teach the devs but do not build walls around them. Discipline should not be enforced by the artifacts but by the devs themselves."_ - That is true, but this new feature makes making errors much more easier; with "private" types being actively proposed by the various autocompletes (IntelliSense, Resharper, etc.) a developer must closely monitor every namespace (automatically) included and even then could have no way of knowing he used a type he shouldn't have.

Comment: I agree with accidently usage but the occurrence should be really low for that. I worried in the past a lot about things like this and over-engineered a lot. I think the time is better invested in code reviews and trust. Dependency tree issues are btw already with legacy NuGet possible, they are just added top-level.