# Projects can reference classes in another projects that aren't directly referenced in .NET Core/.NET Standard

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-core, n-layer

I am designing a N-tier application. The solution has 5 projects: A, B, C, D and E.

The references between projects are like this:

A -> B, E

B -> C, E

C -> D, E

D -> E

Even though I don't have explicit reference from A to D, I can access it without problems by just importing the namespace. When expanding the projects references of A, I see that B is referenced. If I expand A>B then I see C and so on.

Is this by design?

Comment: I get "The type or namespace name 'D' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)", can you post some explicit steps to reproduce your problem, or post the project somewhere?

Comment: I have found another stackoverflow post that solves this problem. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46499409/1930518 . Thanks Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen.