# .NET Core references to other projects breaks the tier isolation

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm building a .NET Core web application using the following projects:

- WebApplication1 (UI)
- BLL
- DAL

As we all know, the UI should only access to the BLL project classes and the BL project should only access to the DAL project classes.

Therefore, i setup the following:

WebApplication1 has a reference to the BLL project only.
BLL has a reference to the DAL project only.

In .NET Framework 4.7 (Not Core), you can not access the DAL classes directly from WebApplication1 unless you explicitly adding a reference to the DAL. it's useful because in that way you will not accidentally access the DAL directly from the WebApplication1 (UI) and you will need to do so via the BLL project.

While i am trying to port from .NET Framework to .NET Core, i found that the behavior has been changed and not i can access the DAL classes directly from WebApplication1 as shown in the screen shoot just by using "using DAL" without the need of adding a reference directly to the DAL.
[image]

The framework automatically shows a reference to the DAL as a "child reference

[image: the framework automatically shows a reference to the DAL as a "child reference"]

Can someone explain about that more?

i want to keep on "well designed" 3 tier isolated architecture and it seems that the new way break that.

Comment: can you please upload pictures of your project properties? (each on of them)

Comment: All default. I just made a sample solution for testing. Could you try to reproduce and see?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Showing classes from indirectly referenced packages in .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37963523/showing-classes-from-indirectly-referenced-packages-in-net-core)

Comment: I dont't agree its dupication because here i am not asking how to disable that. I am asking why Microsoft made the change and what's are the benefits and the disadvantages.

Comment: I have same question. @Omtechguy, did you get any resolution?